# ScrollView does not run properly

Tags: android, scrollview

My Problem is that `ScrollView` not  scrolling more than once I mean when i release the mouse button and hold down again nothing happens nothing moves. It is not working more than once

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hgfdbsfd" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/htrgds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dsds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button04"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/grehgda" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button05"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hgfdbsfd" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button06"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/htrgds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button07"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dsds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button08"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/grehgda" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dsds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dsdsddsdd" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dsdsds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/grehgda" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hgfdbsfd" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/htrgds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dsds" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/grehgda" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/jkkh" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the height of ScrollView to match_parent.

Comment: u want to scroll height 200 dp only dude

Answer (score 3):

try it out.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hgfdbsfd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="htrgds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="grehgda" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button05"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hgfdbsfd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button06"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="htrgds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button07"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button08"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="grehgda" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsdsddsdd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsdsds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="grehgda" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello_world" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hgfdbsfd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="htrgds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsds" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="grehgda" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="jkkh" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Going to be for nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove first LinerLayout and add this code in start.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to scroll the scrollview properly..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hgfdbsfd" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/htrgds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dsds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/grehgda" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button05"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hgfdbsfd" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button06"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/htrgds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button07"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dsds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button08"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/grehgda" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dsds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dsdsddsdd" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dsdsds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/grehgda" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hgfdbsfd" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/htrgds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dsds" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/grehgda" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/jkkh" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```